# Claims authentication replace STSTestCert certificate for production use

Tags: sharepoint, certificate, claims-based-identity

I have created a Custom STS using the claims walkthrough here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955607.aspx.

I would like to use a different certificate now so that we can release this to production and am not sure how to go about this, i.e.

- Do we need to purchase a signed certificate from somewhere?
- What type of certificate should it be?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this by using a self-signed certificate:

```
makecert.exe -sr LocalMachine -ss My -a sha1 -n CN=CertName -sky exchange -r -pe -sk 974877a3-6154-40e4-b688-25fe8962dc17 CertName.cer
certmgr.exe -add -c -n  CN=CertName -s -r localMachine My -s -r localMachine TrustedPeople
```

I then exported this with the private key and imported it into the website and SharePoint servers.